# How to handle the type Maybe a while de- or encoding from/to Json

Tags: decode, encode, elm

I wonder what is the best/prefered way to de-/encode types that contain a field of the type `Maybe a`

Suppose we have the type

```
type alias SomeType =
    { someInt : Int
    , someMaybe : Maybe Float
    , someOtherInt : Int
    }
```

Comment: I'm nor sure I understand the question, as it depends what you want it to map to. but there are several dedicated functions to deal with this, like [`maybe`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#maybe) and [`nullable`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#nullable)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to not include the field in the Json output at all when the value is `Nothing`. When decoding if the field is not present, set the field to `Nothing`.